# How to get hive table format in Java code?

Tags: hive

I tried to check details of format of table using

`show create table test` command

output:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`(
  `c1` boolean, 
  `c2` int, 
  `c3` varchar(30), 
  `c4` char(20))
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://hostname:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='true', 
  'numFiles'='3', 
  'numRows'='3', 
  'rawDataSize'='88', 
  'totalSize'='91', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1458116522')
```

From `INPUTFORMAT` and `OUTPUTFORMAT`, I can tell this is text format.

Similarly, I can get these kind of details using:

`describe extended test`

These are inefficient ways I guess. How to achieve this in a better way using Hive JDBC in Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using Hcatalog api . On connecting to hive metastore, you can get the HCatTable based on your schemaName and tableName. On this HCatTable you can use inputFileFormat and OutputFileFormat to get the same.

If you are coming from java, then please refer the below snippet:

```
String schema = "blending";
HCatClient client = HCatalogClient.getClient(uri);
List<String> tables = client.listTableNamesByPattern(schema, "*");
for(String table : tables) {
    HCatTable hTable = client.getTable(schema, table);
    System.out.println("Table name is :" +hTable.getTableName());
    System.out.println("Input file format is:"+hTable.getInputFileFormat());
    System.out.println("Output file format is:"+hTable.getOutputFileFormat());
}
```