# How get hive table definition programatically in json?

Tags: hive

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689171/how-to-get-hive-table-format-in-java-code) similar question. The problem that I will have `org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.Table` object - any ideas how to request table definition as json? PLease do not post something like `describe table` - this is done via SQL while I need json definition.